# FOR statement conflicting with IF statement in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am creating a fairly simple ping tool which shows in milliseconds how long the server took to respond. If the server does not respond, it shows as it responded in 0ms. I wanted to implement an `If` statement to write `Server failed to respond` in the ListBox rather than it replied in 0ms. The only problem with this is I have a chunk of code which need to be run outside the `If` but continues inside the `If` and involves using the line of code `Next`... This seems to cause the `If` statement to not recognise the `End If` and the `End If` to not recognise the `If`...

Here is my code:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To numberOfPings - 1
        Dim ping As New Ping
        Dim pingRe As PingReply = ping.Send(pingTarget)

        If pingRe.RoundtripTime = 0 Then
            Me.listboxPing.Items.Add("Server failed to respond...")
        Else

            Me.listboxPing.Items.Add("Response from " & pingTarget & " in " & pingRe.RoundtripTime.ToString() & "ms")
            listboxPing.SelectedIndex = listboxPing.Items.Count - 1
            listboxPing.SelectedIndex = -1
            Application.DoEvents()

            Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    Next



    Me.listboxPing.Items.Add("")


        End If
```

Does anyone know of a way I could fix this/get around this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Since your `If` starts inside `For`, it must end inside `For` as well. In other words, `End If` must come before `Next`. It is very much like balancing parentheses.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I understand that but I need the `Next` and `Me.listboxPing.Items.Add("")` to be inside the `Else` of `If`...

Comment: Having `Next` inside `Else` is not possible. Come up with a different structure for your code, such that `Next` is outside the conditional.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I tried what you said by putting `End If` before `Next` and it caused the program to freeze when i tried to ping and then causing my computer to Blue Screen...

Comment: @JackPollock - Zero may be an acceptable response.  The first thing to check is that the ping reply status returned success. If pingRe.Status = IPStatus.Success Then

Comment: @dbasnett How would i use that and where would i put that in my code?

Comment: @JackPollock - I have added an answer that uses a RichTextbox.

Answer (score 1):

If I were going to write code to ping an address and show the results it would look something like this.

```
Dim pingThrd As Threading.Thread

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If pingThrd Is Nothing OrElse pingThrd.ThreadState = Threading.ThreadState.Stopped Then
        RichTextBox1.Clear()
        pingThrd = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf PingIt)
        pingThrd.IsBackground = True
        pingThrd.Start("192.168.33.1")
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub PingIt(pingTarget As Object)
    Dim numberOfPings As Integer = 5
    Dim pingT As String = DirectCast(pingTarget, String)
    Dim pingTimeOut As Integer = 1000
    Const dlyBetweenPing As Integer = 500

    Dim dspStr As String

    For i As Integer = 0 To numberOfPings - 1
        Dim pingit As New Ping
        Dim pingRe As PingReply = pingit.Send(pingT, pingTimeOut)
        'check if success
        If pingRe.Status = IPStatus.Success Then
            dspStr = String.Format("Response from: {0} in {1}ms.", pingRe.Address, pingRe.RoundtripTime)
        Else
            dspStr = String.Format("{0} failed.  Status: {1}", pingRe.Address, pingRe.Status)
        End If
        Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                           RichTextBox1.AppendText(dspStr)
                           RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
                       End Sub)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(dlyBetweenPing)
    Next
End Sub
```

edit:  Same basic code but allow thread to start with different address and count.

```
Structure PingWhat
    Dim addr As String
    Dim howmany As Integer
End Structure

Dim pingThrd As Threading.Thread

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If pingThrd Is Nothing OrElse pingThrd.ThreadState = Threading.ThreadState.Stopped Then
        RichTextBox1.Clear()
        'setup a thread to do the actual ping'ing
        'this allows the UI to function
        pingThrd = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf PingIt)
        pingThrd.IsBackground = True
        'setup address to ping and howmany times to ping it
        Dim somePing As New PingWhat With {.addr = "192.168.33.1", .howmany = 3}
        'start the thread
        pingThrd.Start(somePing)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub PingIt(pingTarget As Object)
    Dim pingT As PingWhat = DirectCast(pingTarget, PingWhat)
    Dim pingTimeOut As Integer = 1000
    Const dlyBetweenPing As Integer = 500

    Dim dspStr As String

    For i As Integer = 1 To pingT.howmany
        Dim pingit As New Ping
        Dim pingRe As PingReply = pingit.Send(pingT.addr, pingTimeOut)
        'check if success
        If pingRe.Status = IPStatus.Success Then
            dspStr = String.Format("Response from: {0} in {1} ms.", pingRe.Address, pingRe.RoundtripTime)
        Else
            dspStr = String.Format("Ping Failed {0}.  Status: {1}", pingT.addr, pingRe.Status)
        End If
        'update the UI
        Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                           RichTextBox1.AppendText(dspStr)
                           RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
                           RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
                       End Sub)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(dlyBetweenPing)
    Next
    Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                       RichTextBox1.AppendText("Done")
                       RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
                       RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
                   End Sub)
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this go somewhere inside my existing code or is it a FULL ping script?

Comment: Full.  Give it a try.  Create a new project with a button and richtextbox.

Comment: And where is the IP entered then by the user? Also does the user have the ability to select how many times the target is pinged?

Comment: @JackPollock - added second example.

Comment: I added in an answer the code i was using previously and was wondering if that could be altered to make the changes i outlined in the answer?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Sorry.

Comment: In the answer i posted not too long ago i explained how when a ping fails is just says for example `192.168.0.18 responded in 0ms` but it hasn't responded so i wanted to have it say `Server failed to respond...` instead...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
For i As Integer = 0 To numberOfPings - 1
        Dim ping As New Ping
        Dim pingRe As PingReply = ping.Send(pingTarget)

        If pingRe.RoundtripTime = 0 Then
            Me.listboxPing.Items.Add("Server failed to respond...")
        Else

            Me.listboxPing.Items.Add("Response from " & pingTarget & " in " & pingRe.RoundtripTime.ToString() & "ms")
            listboxPing.SelectedIndex = listboxPing.Items.Count - 1
            listboxPing.SelectedIndex = -1
            Application.DoEvents()

            Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
            add = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

If add Then Me.listboxPing.Items.Add("")
```

The If will change the scope, therefore, you need to use a variable to check whether it went into the Else part.

Of course, you need to close the first If before the Next.

Comment: That caused my program to freeze up and I had to forcefully close it using task manager... Any suggestions as to why this may have happened? It does not give me any crash report or tells me why it crashed, it just freezes up and refuses to do anything...

Comment: Also after doing this it has stopped the box which defines how times the server will be pinged from working. It justs pings once rather how many times the user defines...

Comment: If it hangs a bit before crashing, I would pause the debugging to see at which statement it gets stuck; that should give you enough information, if it doesn't, I would try to using WinDbg with SOS for more detailed debug information. I can't tell you where is the issue from this code, but I would try not to lock the UI using Tasks rather than Application.DoEvents(), it might be getting stuck before executing the statement and therefore not processing the message queue.

Comment: When I try to ping a server that i know will not respond (because i want to test the `Server did not respond...` message) it hangs on line `Dim pingRe As PingReply = ping.Send(pingTarget)` ...

Comment: You can use "SendAsync" or Send with the timeout parameter; see the example on this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The specific overload page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcc2xffs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: How would I go about implementing that into my code? (Sorry i am not that good at Visual Basic)

Comment: For now, I would try ping.Send(pingTarget, 100); then look at the MSDN example I provided to understand the usage of SendAsync.

Comment: Ok... But do you know of how i could get it to write a certain message like `Server failed to respond...` in the listbox rather that it saying that the server responded in 0ms. Do you know how i would do that after the timeout time defined in `ping.send(pingTarget, 2000)?

Answer (score 0):

@dbasnett This was the code I using before and it was absolutely perfect for what i needed EXCEPT if a ping failed it would just say `(PingTarget) responded in 0ms` which is not ideal. Ideally i would like it to say `Server failed to respond...` . Do you know a way in which this can be achieved by modifying my original code?

```
    Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class PingClient



    Private Const EM_SETCUEBANNER As Integer = &H1501

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal lParam As String) As Int32
    End Function

    Private Sub SetCueText(ByVal control As Control, ByVal text As String)
        SendMessage(control.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub PingClient_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SetCueText(textboxIP, "IP Address/Domain")
        SetCueText(textboxPing, "No. Of Pings")
    End Sub

Structure PingWhat
    Dim addr As String
    Dim howmany As Integer
End Structure

Dim pingThrd As Threading.Thread

Public Sub buttonPing_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonPing.Click

    If pingThrd Is Nothing OrElse pingThrd.ThreadState = Threading.ThreadState.Stopped Then
        Dim pingTarget As String = ""
        Dim numberOfPings As Integer = 0
        Dim intTimeout As Integer = 2000

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxIP.Text) Then
            MsgBox("You must enter an IP Address or Domain.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Not Int32.TryParse(textboxPing.Text, numberOfPings) Then
            MsgBox("You must enter a number of how many times the target address will be pinged.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If numberOfPings = 0 Then
            MsgBox("You must enter a value over 0.")
            textboxPing.Clear()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'setup a thread to do the actual ping'ing
        'this allows the UI to function
        pingThrd = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf PingIt)
        pingThrd.IsBackground = True
        'setup address to ping and howmany times to ping it
        Dim somePing As New PingWhat With {.addr = pingTarget, .howmany = numberOfPings}
        'start the thread
        pingThrd.Start(somePing)
    End If

    Me.listboxPing.Items.Add("")

End Sub

Public Sub PingIt(pingTarget As Object)
    Dim pingT As PingWhat = DirectCast(pingTarget, PingWhat)
    Dim pingTimeOut As Integer = 1000
    Const dlyBetweenPing As Integer = 500

    Dim dspStr As String

    For i As Integer = 1 To pingT.howmany
        Dim pingit As New Ping
        Dim pingRe As PingReply = pingit.Send(pingT.addr, pingTimeOut)
        'check if success
        If pingRe.Status = IPStatus.Success Then
            dspStr = String.Format("Response from: {0} in {1} ms.", pingRe.Address, pingRe.RoundtripTime)
        Else
            dspStr = String.Format("Ping Failed {0}.  Status: {1}", pingT.addr, pingRe.Status)
        End If
        'update the UI
        Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                           listboxPing.Items.Add(dspStr)
                       End Sub)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(dlyBetweenPing)
    Next
    Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                       listboxPing.Items.Add("Done")
                   End Sub)
End Sub


    Private Sub PingClient_Closing(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
        Dim Response As Integer
        Response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit the Ping Tool?", 36)

        If Response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

        Else

            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: That code looks very much like parts of mr dbasnett's answer.  Surely, he deserves an upvote for helping, no?  It doesnt cost you anything to upvote any post anywhere that you learn from.  One vote in 10 months seems a bit sparse.